# JavaFX sizes doubts

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

If I have a window with a BorderPane and its size properties are:

- Min Width: USE_PREF_SIZE.
- Min Height: USE_PREF_SIZE.
- Pref Width: 600.
- Pref Height: 400.
- Max Width: USE_PREF_SIZE.
- Max Height: USE_PREF_SIZE.

Why can I resize the window? I haven't clear how works these properties (I read the API and I still don't understand).

Comment: What does this have to do with recursion?

Comment: I have made a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The min/max/pref width and height of a `Region` are used by a parent layout pane to determine how to size and position the child nodes of that pane. So if you put your border pane in a parent which manages layout (i.e. a subclass of `Pane`), then those settings would be adhered to, if possible.

However, a `Scene` is not a layout pane and basically performs no layout. It has one `root` node (a `Parent` instance), and simply sizes the root to the size of the `Scene`. In turn, the scene is sized by the window and takes on the size of the window minus any space needed for a window border and decorations.

Consequently, these settings on your `BorderPane` have no effect on the resizability of the window. To turn off the ability to resize the window, use the *window* method `setResizable(false)`. Similarly, if you want to impose minimum or maximum sizes on the window, use the *window's* min/max width/height properties.